# For-loop error in c

Tags: c, for-loop

I've downloaded a program which seems to have an error at the line:

```
for(i=0; i<SIZE_OF_DATA; i--){
```

in main.c, however as a newbie programmer I'm not too sure how to resolve it.

Here's main.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "util.h"

#define SIZE_OF_DATA 10

int main(void) {
    int data[SIZE_OF_DATA];

    generateRandomData(data, SIZE_OF_DATA);


    int i;
    for(i=0; i<SIZE_OF_DATA; i--){
        printf("%d: %d\n",i,data[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `i--` to `i++` in `for(i=0; i<SIZE_OF_DATA; i--)`.

Comment: Did you actually run this and see printed `i` going down to negative values? I'd think that would be pretty clear indication of what's wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you use `i--`. So the loop will count backwards, i.e. 0, -1, -2, -3 and so on and will **always** be smaller than `SIZE OF DATA`

The correct code would be

```
for(i=0; i<SIZE_OF_DATA; i++) {
```

Otherwise you'll have a perfect infinite loop :)

Comment: `INT_MIN - 1` is undefined behavior. So not necessarily an infinite loop. But possibly.

Comment: Yes, it will probably warp at `-2147483648`. But that hasn't much relevance here for understanding the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need

```
for(i=0; i<SIZE_OF_DATA; i++)
```

instead of

```
for(i=0; i<SIZE_OF_DATA; i--)
```

`i--` means that the value of `i` will be 0 then `-1,-2...` which you dont want. `SIZE_OF_DATA` will be a positive value and hence the for loop will result in an infinite loop and hence your problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Choose any one**

1.`for(i=0; i<SIZE_OF_DATA; i++)`

2.`for(i=SIZE_OF_DATA -1 ; i>=0; i--)`

1.You are starting your loop from `0` to `SIZE_OF_DATA`. Since you are progressing towards your size so you should increment your iterator `i`.

2.You are doing the opposite here ; `i` is set to the last position i.e `SIZE_OF_DATA - 1` and now you have to decrement your iterator `i` till you reach 0.

**Note**
In your code , you are starting from 0 and going towards negative side with `i--`. Your exit condition for `for` loop `i<SIZE_OF_DATA` will remain true always. This can cause you serious issues

1.Segmentation fault (accessing a negative index in the array `data[]` i.e `data[i]` and i is going towards negative integers).

2.Infinite loop as your termination condition will is always true. (It has to be false to come out of the loop).